# Trigger an exception if it is not an integer between 0 and 7 inclusively

Tags: python

```
        try:
            psl = int(input("Source Position - Line Number: "))
            psc = int(input("Source Position - Column Number: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: you have to enter an integer between 0 and 7 inclusively\n")
            continue
```

In that little piece of code, a player have to enter two integers between 0 and 7 inclusively corresponding to a line and a column. I realised that if I enter `9`, the exception is never triggered. How can I trigger the exception if an integer is not in the range [0, 7]?

Comment: Can you show us what exactly `Pos()` and `self.validation_ps()` are doing? Without it, it will be hard to tell anything...

Comment: We really need to see more code for context, but you probably want to throw/raise the custom exception in the validation_ps method and catch it in your main loop

Comment: @errata `Pos` is just a position is a checkerboard. So you can instantiate it as `my_position = Pos(3,2)`. If there a black piece at that position, `Pos` has some methods to verify where are available target positions for that piece. This is just an instance

Comment: @chessguy You will have to update your answer and provide more code, you're obviously doing something wrong in one of those two methods (probably validation one?) but we cannot guess what...

Comment: I would simplify my code. You don't need to know what `Pos()` and `self.validation_ps()` are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to raise an exception, use the `raise` keyword.

For example:

```
        try:
            psl = int(input("Source Position - Line Number: "))
            psc = int(input("Source Position - Column Number: "))
            if not (0 <= psl <= 7 and 0 <= psc <= 7):
                raise ValueError   # <==== here
            self.pss = Pos(psl, psc)
            validation = self.validation_ps(self.pss)
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: you have to enter an integer between 0 and 7 inclusively\n")
            continue
```

You can also give it an associated error message:

```
                 raise ValueError("you entered a bad number")
```

and then to make use of that, you would need to capture the exception in a variable (typically `exc`) in the `except` block, for example:

```
        except ValueError as exc:
            print("the error was ", exc)
            # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a statement like:

```py
if not (psl in range(0,8) and psc in range(0,8)):
    raise ValueError('Error: you have to enter an integer between 0 and 7 inclusively\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider an assertion to handle the logic while keeping your exception for non-numeric inputs.

```
try:
    psl = int(input("Source Position - Line Number: "))
    psc = int(input("Source Position - Column Number: "))
    assert (0 <= psl <= 7 and 0 <= psc <= 7), 'Please enter a values between 0 and 7'
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter a number!)
```

Comment: According to https://dbader.org/blog/python-assert-tutorial - which I think I agree with - assertions are intended as a debugging tool (testing for conditions which you believe to be impossible) rather than a way to handle run-time errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you're trying to do something like this:

```
while True:
    psl = input("Source Position - Line Number: ")
    psc = input("Source Position - Column Number: ")

    if all([psl.isdigit(), psc.isdigit()]):
        if all([7 >= int(psl) >= 0, 7 >= int(psc) >= 0]):
            break
    print("Error: you have to enter an integer between 0 and 7 inclusively\n")

self.pss = Pos(psl, psc)
validation = self.validation_ps(self.pss)
```

Comment: I got `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Some_String'` if I use `int(input(...))` without using `try/except`. This is an issue

Comment: You get the error if you input something rather than integers.